# Ember tooltip over d3 and html element - with variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, d3.js, tooltip

I need tooltip plugin for ember, which i put just one-time per component and then i could change content of tootltip from component and show it under current hovering element. I have charts in d3 and i need on hover to each element of chart show tooltip with detail of element, this tooltip should stay showed if user moves to tooltip.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Add the text you'd like displayed by the tooltip to your objects which contain the component(s). Example: `component.tooltip = "This is an example component tooltip";` then, `component.displayTooltip();` or `TooltipDisplay.displayComponent(component);`

Comment: @AndrueAnderson and which plugin you mean? Now i have component which i wrote, that get position of element a show content, but its doesnt work very well, so i hope that i can find some good plugin. And to clarify the tooltip has variables in body which i filling in component, so thats not just plain text. And the main problem is with get correct position and display tooltip just one-times when i move over element (not still doing show/hide => flashing).

Comment: This site is more about reusable answers to generic questions than specific code fixes, I've tried to answer in a general way, applying knowledge to your specific situation is up to you my friend.